# paypal - invoice field not returned

Tags: paypal

Payment is created using IOS SDK. Invoice field is set on payment - and it is returned in payment confirmation (on IOS). When I request for payment using this API https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#look-up-a-payment-resource on server, it is returned with transactions, payer etc, everything but invoice field (also tried with custom field). Using sandbox API. How can I get invoice number/custom field by payment id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

Contrary to what I posted just a moment ago about a possible PayPal server bug, we've now done a bit more investigation.

The invoice-number and custom fields should be coming through just fine for *PayPal* payments. However, if you try a Credit Card payment you will not currently see these fields. The credit card issue should be resolved within the next few weeks.

Comment: Good to hear :). So I am waiting - where I will find latest changes or something like this so I could know that issue is resolved? thanks.

Comment: The best way to keep up with our SDK is to "watch" our github repo: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK

Comment: Since this is a server issue rather than an SDK issue, though, the simplest and most reliable way to check on it will be to just try a credit card payment in the Sandbox or Live environment from time to time, to see if the invoice number and custom fields have started to come through.